# Disjoint union and homeomorphism of canonical injection

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

Definition:
Suppose $(X_i)_i$ is an indexed family of non-empty topological spaces. Recall: $\coprod_{i\in I}X_i = $ $\{$ $(x,i)$ $:$ $x\in X_i$ and $i\in I$ $\}$ . There is a canonical injection $\sigma_i: X_i \rightarrow \coprod_{i\in I}X_i$ , given by $\sigma_i(x)=(x,i)$. We usually identify each set $X_i$ with its image, $X_i^*=\sigma_i(X_i)$.

Problem:
Let $(X_i)$ be a collection of non-empty topological spaces.

The the canonical injection $\sigma_i:X_i \rightarrow X_i^*$   is a homeomorphism.

My attempt:

Observe  that $\sigma_i$ $:$ $X_i$ $\rightarrow \coprod_{i\in I}X_i$ is by definition, continuous for each $i\in I$. Hence restricting its codomain, to $\sigma_i(X_i)$ yields a continuous function. Observe that for $i\in I$, $\sigma_i^{-1}(x,i)=x$ is the inverse of $\sigma_i$, hence $\sigma_i$ is a bijection.

My question is: **How do I show that $\sigma_i^{-1}$ is also continuous?**

Comment: The topology on $\bigsqcup X_i$ is defined such that $\sigma_i$ are all embeddings. More explicitly it is the finest topology such that all of the $\sigma_i$ are embeddings.

Comment: @NoelLundström It is defined as the finest topology such that all $\sigma_i$ are continuous.

Comment: @PaulFrost Since all of the $\sigma_i$ are injective they are equivalent statements. But you're right of course, that is a more correct definition.

Comment: @NoelLundström Yes, it is just a special case of a final topology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basic fact: if $f:X\to Y$ is a bijection between spaces TFAE:

- $f$ is a homeomorphism.
- $f$ is open and continuous.
- $f$ is closed and continuous.

And we already proved that $\sigma_i$ is open ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/3543583/4280)) and a bijection between $ X_i$ and its image $X_i^\ast$.

Comment: I’m sorry, I don’t see how I proved that $\sigma_i$ is open. May you elaborate, please? All I see is that I have proved that $\sigma_i$ to $X_i^*$ is continuous and bijective.

Comment: @topologicalmagician I added a link. The answer to your previous question on this very subject....

Comment: You're completely right. I forgot about it. My apologies.

Comment: @topologicalmagician now you won’t forget it any more. Note that all $X_i^\ast$ are also closed in the sum space.

Answer (score 0):

For this, you just need to observe that an open set $U \subseteq \coprod_{i\in I}X_i$ is of the form $U = \coprod_{j \in I}U_j^*$ where $U_j^*$ is open in $X_j^*$ for all $j \in I$. But now

$$\sigma^{-1}_i(U) = \sigma_i^{-1}(\coprod_{j \in I}U_j^*) = 
\sigma^{-1}_i(U_i^*) = U_i$$